# VS Code syntax highlighting broken when editing LLVM code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

I am working on the LLVM source tree using the VS Code editor. I am unable to get the editor to find the identifiers correctly. It mistakenly throws errors on a lot of defined classes. I have tried modifying the include path but the issue persists. The current include path is `${workspaceFolder}/**`.

[image]